# Setting connections.max.idle.ms does not work for Kafka Connect using Docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to set `connections.max.idle.ms` property, but it doesn't seem to be working.
According to kafka documentation all is needed is to add a prefix `CONNECT_` and replace periods with underscores.
Here's how I'm trying to set it in my **docker-compose** file:

```
environment:
      CONNECT_CONNECTIONS_MAX_IDLE_MS: 10000
...
```

but when I'm checking the logs of kafka connect the property is remaining unchanged:

```
    [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - AdminClientConfig values: 
        bootstrap.servers = [kafka:29092]
        client.dns.lookup = default
        client.id = 
        connections.max.idle.ms = 300000
...
```

I'm using `confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.2.2` docker image.

Could you please point me to what I'm doing wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: What docker image do you use?

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander `confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.2.2` I should've provided this information right off the bat, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

`CONNECT_` variables are only passed into `connect-distributed.properties`

That property does not exist for Connect, only the AdminClient, therefore, assuming that AdminClient properties are configurable in a way [they are for producers and consumers](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/references/allconfigs.html#override-the-worker-configuration) (for example, `consumer.override.max.poll.records`, which would be `CONNECT_CONSUMER_OVERRIDE_MAX_POLL_RECORDS`), then you would need to adjust your variable accordingly.

Also, 5 minutes is a long timeout time, as it is. There is no reason to shorten it

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply, I've tried using `CONNECT_ADMIN_OVERRIDE_CONNECTIONS_MAX_IDLE_MS` and `CONNECT_CONSUMER_OVERRIDE_CONNECTIONS_MAX_IDLE_MS`, but still no changes

Comment: I never said that was the solution... Mostly because that doesn't work, and isn't documented as working in the link I gave